# NoMethodError undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm have a problem. When create follow author, I'm getting error:

```
NoMethodError in FollowsController#create_author

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is the route

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :follows, only: %i(create destroy create_author destroy_author)
 post "/follows/create_author", to: "follows#create_author", as: :create_author
 delete "/follows/destroy_author/:id", to: "follows#destroy_author", as: :destroy_author
end
```

Here is the form

```
<%= form_for(@follow, as: :create_author, url: create_author_path, remote: true) do |f| %>
  %= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id if current_user != nil %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :type_follow, value: "author" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :follower_id, value: @author.id %>
  <%= f.submit t(".submit"), id: "follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Here is the controller
[enter link controller here](https://github.com/NguyenThiHangB/brs_66/blob/follow-unfollow-authors/app/controllers/follows_controller.rb)

Help please :( Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the code from the `create_author` method in your `FollowsController`?

Comment: Link controller: https://github.com/NguyenThiHangB/brs_66/blob/follow-unfollow-authors/app/controllers/follows_controller.rb

Comment: Can you show the server logs?

Answer (score 0):

When posting an error like this it would help us figure it out if you would include the line number and at least some of the stack trace.  Without that we won't have much to go on to help.

That said, the one place you use `[]` in your controller is at the bottom in the `find_user` and `find_author` methods. Specifically you do `params[:follow][:follower_id]`. If `params[:follow]` is nil, then the error you get would make sense.

Couple of things to do..

- Verify in your rails log that the parameters you think are being sent to your controller are in fact being sent.
- Adjust those two methods to use `follow_params` not `params`.

Good luck!